# Rotate touch input on android

Tags: root-access

Is there a way I can edit touch input on android? The best way i can explain it is I want to rotate my touch inputs by (-1°). Without the display actually being rotated. This is a feature that ive been begging for a developer to put in a certain game but since its nearly impossible im looking for a work around by doing it on my device.  From what I've researched is only possible by editing build.prop. which is only accessible with root. Is there any way for me to achieve this on my device?